# How do I get the exit code of a process that's piped to tee?

Tags: mac-osx, bash, shell

I have bash code like this (Mac OS X):

`foo.sh | tee foo.log
echo $?`

The problem is that $? contains the exit code of tee and not the exit code of foo.sh.  How do I get the exit code of foo.sh?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871859/piping-command-output-to-tee-but-also-save-exit-code-of-command

Answer (score 7):

The environment variable `$PIPESTATUS` is an array of exit statuses for all processes in a pipeline.

Comment: Why'd you ask the question if you know the answer?

Comment: Probably for the same reason there's a button to "answer your own question".

Comment: @Patrick I didn't know the answer when I asked the question, but did some more digging and found it.

Answer (score 3):

Also use a subshell:

```
tm@hoegaarden:~$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "stuff and junk"

exit 123
tm@hoegaarden:~$ (./foo.sh ; echo $? > ./retval ) | tee output
stuff and junk
tm@hoegaarden:~$ cat retval 
123
```

Comment: This is more portable (not specific to `bash`) - hence upvote.